# Error always thrown loading UIImage from URL

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, swift3, xcode8

When I try to load an image from a URL I always get an error despite the fact that I know that there is a URL that contains a valid .jpg image.

```
mainImageView.image = try UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: artworkURL)))
```

I also tried [these solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift) but the line where I initialise the `UIImage` still throws an error.

Example of data in `artworkURL`:

http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/ef/97/95/ef979538-8321-151a-dceb-9b0a7f7c7641/source/100x100bb.jpg

Current solutions do not solve my problem. I also tried:

```
try UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: URL(string: artworkURL)!))
```

and

```
try UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: (URL : artworkURL)))
```

and (fuller code) now using a static url to debug

```
let artworkString = "http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/ef/97/95/ef979538-8321-151a-dceb-9b0a7f7c7641/source/100x100bb.jpg" // album.artworkURL[index.row]
let url = URL(string: artworkString)

do {
    mainImageView.image = try UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: url!))
} catch _ {
    print("No album artwork!")
}
```

This last one outputs `"No album artwork!"`!

Comment: @EricAya I *am* using try!!!

Comment: @MaxGoodridge Then it should work. Look at [my screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOwJ4q4PUmlArK-NlffFMDt-DwjjnWho8Fs), using your exact same code. Your issue is elsewhere, not here.

Comment: I can't answer my own question for some reason but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31807139/4548304) is the answer!! I had to add a breakpoint (for the first time) to find the error.

Comment: @EricAya Duely noted - I learned a lot about how to actually debug code using Xcode trying to find the solution. Please forgive me for my lack of competence debugging in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can user this library:

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

> Kingfisher is a lightweight, pure-Swift library for downloading and caching images from the web. This project is heavily inspired by the popular SDWebImage. It provides you a chance to use a pure-Swift alternative in your next app.

```
let imagePath = URL(string: "url_of_your_image")    
imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imagePath)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
```

you can also add placeholder image.